# How to add shortcode in post wordpress correctly?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi all I am a new of wordpress I try to add I download plugin photo galarry and I try to put shortcode in post but its show as text ,who can help me pleast ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put shortcode in a post or page by using below code

```
[YourShortCode]
```

Or in your php page or template file put below code

```
echo do_shortcode( '[YourShortCode]' );
```

Comment: I try this but stiil as text.

Comment: it is like :                    [URIS id=885] Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries

Comment: are you giving shortcode in post or in widget?

Comment: http://westecmedia.com/events-2/

Comment: Please add this code in to your functions.php file. Hopefully it works :)

Comment: add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');

Comment: [URIS id='885'] must work

Comment: hm sorry bro not work :(

Comment: http://westecmedia.com/events-2/

Comment: maby my wordpress site old version

Comment: this website I continue from other webdeveloper

Comment: So I not dare to update its

Comment: which version of wordpress you are using?

Comment: I use wordpress 4.0.8

Comment: I am sorry but there must be some issue with your plugin or its activation  otherwise at least one of the above suggested change should work :(

Comment: Ok k thank q brother

Comment: Are you adding it to the post using the Visual-tab, not HTML?

Comment: Both brother , now im chang plugin slide I am customize myselft photo gallry brother

Answer (score 0):

It would have been nice if I knew what plugin you intend to use as the shortcode will depend on the plugin. Nonetheless, shortcode can be as simple as what you see below.

```
[gallery]
```

Some plugins allow you to pass additional information into the shortcode as seen in the example below.

```
[gallery id="123" size="medium"]
```

In both cases above, the shortcode used the keyword `gallery` and will depending on the plugin you use. The plug should also provide some instruction or example of the shortcode. These shortcodes can be inserted in the body of a post or page and can even in inserted in a text widget.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I try ur code but still as text

Comment: example:     [URIS id=885] Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your shortcode in brackets. You can put this in post or page.
Example:

```
 [your_shortcode]
```

Or in php template page use

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode('[your_shortcode]');?>
```

If you still found as text. It could be either your plugin is not activated yet or your shortcode is not working.